# Get all related categories by manufacturer, 5 tables

Tags: mysql, relational-database

Building report for a store and trying to get categories by manufacturer id. Not luck doing MySQL queries (experience almost null hehe) but I have this:

[image: manufacturer-product-product_category-category-category_description]

### Table schema

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `table` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ;
USE `table` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `table`.`category_description`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table`.`category_description` (
  `category_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `table`.`category`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table`.`category` (
  `category_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `image` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `table`.`manufacturer`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table`.`manufacturer` (
  `manufacturer_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `name` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`manufacturer_id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `table`.`product`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table`.`product` (
  `product_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `manufacturer_id` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`) ,
  INDEX `product_manufacturer` (`manufacturer_id` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `table`.`product_category`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table`.`product_category` (
  `product_id` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  `category_id` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`, `category_id`) ,
  INDEX `product_to_category_product_id` (`product_id` ASC) ,
  INDEX `product_to_category_category_id` (`category_id` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- Sorry if example data is not provided
```

### MySQL query

```
SELECT category_description.name, category.category_id
FROM manufacturer
  JOIN product ON product.manufacturer_id = manufacturer.manufacturer_id
  JOIN product_to_category ON product_to_category.product_id = product.product_id
  JOIN category ON category.category_id = product_to_category.category_id
  JOIN category_description ON category_description.category_id = category.category_id
  WHERE manufacturer.manufacturer_id = 7
```

The query result has many `category_description.name` repeated rows (inherited from my newbie-query I guess)

Schema is based on products and the idea is when a manufacturer is selected then all categories related to its products are obtained (unique).

I'm stock due to my lack of knowledge in building queries

**Edited**: So sorry, corrected `category` table row name (`category.image` instead `category.name`)

Comment: Providing a schema is good. It would be better if you put in 2-3 rows in each table, and threw the whole thing on http://sqlfiddle.com so people can play with it. Just by eyeballing the thing, I think you're just missing `DISTINCT`: `SELECT DISTINCT category_description.name...`

Comment: Schema is ready here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84a8b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go ([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a740f/6/0)):

```
SELECT DISTINCT category_description.name, category.category_id
FROM product
  JOIN product_category ON product_category.product_id = product.product_id
  JOIN category ON category.category_id = product_category.category_id
  JOIN category_description ON category_description.category_id = category.category_id
  WHERE product.manufacturer_id = 1
```

a) Don't link tables you don't need

b) use `DISTINCT` to clean up the dupes generated by once-distinct data (i.e. products, here) that got snipped.

c) don't misspell table names :p